# creating multiple stringbuilders WTR to count

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

If i have a count say item =5. I want to generate 5 string builder objs. How can this be done?

```
string[] features = UserBL.GetFeaturesByRole(Session["Role"].ToString().Trim()).TrimEnd(',').Split(',');
```

in features i will have features. So according to the count i need to generate stringbuilder objs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create an array based on the count?

```
var builders = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(x => new StringBuilder()).ToArray();
```

then to get the second builder you can do

```
var builder = builders[1];
```

Comment: in your case: `features.Select(item => new StringBuilder(item)).ToList();` will get you an Collection of StringBuilders for each Feature, containing the feature text itself. use the default .ctor() to create empty StringBuilders. ToList() is needed if you want to access the collection several times, because without, you would always reiterate and thus recreate new StringBuilders.

Comment: @eFloh he has `ToArray`, which resolves the `Enumerable` just as efficiently as `ToList` does, plus the added benefit of making `builders` immutable. However, +1 for noting that he can bypass the `Enumerable.Range` business and enumerate straight off his `features` string array, initializing each `StringBuilder` in-line.

Comment: @JohnCastleman nice and useful extension about ToArray/ToList. But the array is only immutable concerning the size, not the contents. In this case, as a local variable this shouldn't be a problem. When the Builders are exposed, e.g. as property, I would strongly recommend an `IReadOnlyCollection` if one needs to protect against this "array attack" ;)